# Use Looper or not?

Tags: android, android-looper

Android docs on `Looper` are not clear in stating whether we shall use `Looper` or not. I have seen many places saying not to use `Looper` with `Handler`, but to use `AsyncTask` or some similar non-main thread methodology.

So shall we ever use `Looper` or not?

If yes, when me have to use it (not must or should)? Only when passing UI update message from the thread to the main thread or there are some other cases as well?

Comment: `some similar non-main thread methodology.` Which is the key to answer your question: too much work on your main thread may cause crashes,

Comment: That was my idea years ago when I started learning Android. But now, each time I am interviewed for a senior position, I am asked "do you use Looper, why and when". Obviously all seniors in those companies are using it... which is the reason I asked the question.

Comment: then answer those seniors: `no i am always using a HandlerThread`, its docs say: `Handy class for starting a new thread that has a looper. The looper can then be used to create handler classes. Note that start() must still be called.`